# Check ENS domain availability onchain

Tags: solidity-0.8.x, ens

I was trying to build an ENS domain check utility in solidity. Is it possible to check the validity of an ENS address directly on chain?

Found this [contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0x283af0b28c62c092c9727f1ee09c02ca627eb7f5#readContract),  and its `available` looks what I want, but regardless of what I give it returns true.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The available function in the contract is to check if the ens is available to me minted.
[image: ens available function]

When the name is already minted then you will get ntn returned at bool. (I'm assuming false should be there instead being empty)

[image]

All the name you entered would have been able to be minted.